# How do I share Google+ photos automatically?

Tags: photo-sharing, google-plus-photos

My wife and I each have Android phones with separate Google accounts. Each of us takes photos with our phones, and they are automatically backed up using Google Photo Backup (i.e., to Google+). We'd like to share these backed up photos with each other (since they are mostly of our child) without having to manually share each photo (since that's a pain). Any ideas on making this happen automatically? Sharing between the phones is ideal, but it would also be nice to see all of them on a desktop/laptop computer when we are logged into either Google account.

Comment: I think automatically sharing not possible, can just automatically back up photos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just recently Google made it possible to do that through Google Drive.

Now in the Google Drive application, there is a folder named `Google Photos`, you can click on it and have your Google+ photos showing up also in Google Drive.

Then you can share this Google Drive folder like any other with your wife.
All the future photos you take and auto-backup on Google+ will also be automatically available in this folder on your wife's Google Drive account.

Comment: This worked for me but first I had to enable `Auto Add`. Automatically put Google Photos into a folder in 'My Drive'. I changed this setting in the Android app.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Andrea Zonca's answer (which essentially helped my problem), some things I noticed (maybe less relevant to the topic but still things to consider when you decide the option to share pics on photos using drive):

- While the status on `photos` seems to be reflected on `drive` immediately, the other way round may not hold; for insntance, when I remove a picture on `photos`, the corresponding file on `drive` gets removed. But even when I removed one on `drive`, it still remains on `photos`.
- `drive` seems to keep duplicate of some of my files that don't exist on `photos`; If you look at the file property of a file on drive, it has `Size` and `Storage used`, and for those duplicate files "Storage used" is 0 bytes. Although I don't know what this means, I ended up manually removing those duplicate files because they just clutter my drive.